# Eclipse: Add class to startup classpath

Tags: eclipse

I have a plugin that uses a JRE class that was removed in Java 8. I want to add that class to the Eclipse startup classpath so that it is available to the plugin. The Java 8 endorsement mechanism, which appears to be deprecated, doesn't seem to allow adding the class to the JRE.

Comment: Each Eclipse plugin has its own separate classpath. Add the class/jar to the plugin.

Comment: Make that an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Eclipse plugin has its own separate classpath. Plugins can only reference classes in the plugin or in other plugins on their classpath. The classpath is defined by the 'Require-Bundle', 'Import-Package' and 'Bundle-ClassPath' entries in the plugin's MANIFEST.MF.

So if you have additional classes add them to the plugin.

You can also add extra jars to the plugin by adding them to the 'Bundle-ClassPath' entry in the MANIFEST.MF and updating the 'build.properties' to include the jar.